# How to access a GridPane that I inserted into a VBox in JavaFX?

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, javafx

so i'm working on a college project, to make Minesweeper basically. I made a VBox, inside the VBox I have so far a TextField, Button and a GridPane. I want to access the GridPane but for some reason lets say the instance of the VBox which contains my GridPane is called root, if I do root.getChildren().get(2), (it was inserted after the button and textfield) it gives me an error. Also it doesn't allow me to convert it to GridPane even though I imported everything. Here is the code:

```
public class MainApp extends Application{
    private Mines mainGame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("MineSweeper");
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root = (VBox) makeVBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,700,700,Color.AQUAMARINE);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    
        System.out.println(root.getChildren().get(2).getClass());
    }
    
    private Parent makeVBox()
    {
        TextField input = new TextField();
        input.setMaxSize(200, 100);
        Button b = new Button("Start");
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(input, b);
        b.setOnAction(action -> {
            if(input.getText().matches("[0-9]+"))
            {
                this.mainGame = new Mines(Integer.parseInt(input.getText()),Integer.parseInt(input.getText()),10);
                GridPane grid = new GridPane();
                for(int i=0; i<this.mainGame.returnMines().length; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<this.mainGame.returnMines()[i].length; j++)
                    {
                        Button button = new Button(String.valueOf(this.mainGame.returnMines()[i][j].getMine()));
                        grid.add(button, j, i);
                    }
                }
                root.getChildren().add(grid);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
    

}
```

this is the error that i'm getting when I try `System.out.println(root.getChildren().get(2).getClass());`

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
    at JFX.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:32)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application JFX.MainApp
```

It basically doesn't recognize that there is a GridPane in index 2. It does however recognize that there is a textfield and a button in index 1 and 2.

Comment: Index starts at 0. Index 2 refers to the 3rd position and `root` only has 2 elements. *Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2*

Answer (score 0):

You have added a `Button` and a `Label` to your `VBox`. The third element of the list of `children`, the `GridPane`, gets added only when the event handler for the button is called.
 You are getting this error because the line `System.out.println(root.getChildren().get(2).getClass());` is executed before there is a chance to add the `GridPane` to the `VBox`.